# cakephp update more field unique

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a site developed in cakephp.
I have a model called User like this:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'not_empty' => array(
                'rule'=> 'notEmpty',
                'message'=> 'Username not empty'    
            )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email_invalid' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Invalid mail'
            ),
            'email_unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Mail already exist inside database'
            )
        )
    );


    public function beforeSave(){
           if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])){
            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }   
}
```

Into my validate I have the rules `email_unique` that check if inside the database is already present another email equal.

When I update a user I make this inside my controller:

```
$this->User->id = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->redirect (array ('action'=>'index'));
}
else{
    $this->Session->write('flash_element','error');
    $this->Session->setFlash ('Error');
}
```

It always fail because email isn't unique but is the same record!

I would like to know what is the best method to escape the validation if the save is an update not a create?
Or something like: check if the page is edit escape validation or I don't know.. maybe there are many system, I would like to know what is the more correct for my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your validation rules to only apply when a new record is created, not when an existing record is updated. You can do this by setting the `on` key in your validation rule to `create`, so it will look like this:

```
'email_unique' => array(
    'rule' => 'isUnique',
    'message' => 'Mail already exist inside database',
    'on' => 'create' // Only apply this rule upon creation of a new record
)
```

See [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#on) on this for further details.

If you also want to block duplicate e-mails upon updating, create a [beforeSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) method in your User model, looking for the e-mail address:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    // If the email key is set in the data to be saved...
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['email'])) {
        // Make sure the email is not already in use by another user
        if ($this->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                $this->alias . '.id !=' => $this->data[$this->alias]['id'],
                $this->alias . '.email' => $this->data[$this->alias]['email']
            )
        )) > 0) {
          // The email is found for a user with another id, abort!
          return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...  So what if you update an existing record with an email that is already in another record?

Comment: Great point @AbraCadaver because is a very little problem but not so easy to do

Comment: In that case, use `beforeSave` to do the double-check. See updated answer.