# Email Validation in cakephp Model

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have the below setup of validation rules. For some reason, `'on' => 'create'` block doesn't work. The conditions to be implemented are standard create / modify regarding email. Also, in edit section, I'm getting the error from `'on' => 'create'` block.

How to validate the email? I'm using CakePHP v 2.6.1.

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Kindly provide your email for verification.'
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 255),
            'message' => 'Email cannot be more than 255 characters.'
        ),
        'editunique' => array(
            'rule' => array('editunique'),
            'message' => 'Provided Email address already exists.',
            'on' => 'update'
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Provided Email already exists.',
            'on' => 'create'
        )
    )
);


public function editunique($email) {
    // email should be one and of the logged in user only.
    if ($this->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            $this->alias . '.id <>' => $this->data[$this->alias]['id'],
            $this->alias . '.email' => $email
        )
    )) > 1) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Also, I'm not getting the `$this->data[$this->alias]['id']` value.

My Controller has the following section:

```
if ($this->Client->hasAny(array('Client.id' => base64_decode(trim($this->request->query['client_id']))))){
            if ( $this->request->is('ajax') && $this->request->is('post') ){
                $this->Client->create();
                $this->Client->id = base64_decode(trim($this->request->query['client_id']));
                $this->Client->set($this->request->data);
                // validate
                if($this->Client->validates()) {
                    // save the data after validation
                    if($this->Client->save($this->request->data)){
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
```

Comment: ok, to get `$this->data[$this->alias]['id']` value, change to `$this->id`. So getting the set id now but problem with create persists.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your custom validation rule? That looks to replicate Cake's own `isUnique` validation rule.

Comment: yes that is for uniqueness but on update of profile details. Actually I took the function from this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20203538/3007408. While that answer tells to use in before save, i'm using it during validation.

Comment: Then why not remove the `editunique` rule and drop the `on` condition of your `unique` rule as unless I've missed something that would do the same thing with much less code. Cake's `isUnique` takes into account the current record's value so won't complain of duplicates on updating if the email is only used on the current data.

Comment: oh, didn't knew that. Although i've not check the registration part but seems to work for the edit. Thanks.

Comment: That's great. I've added this as an answer to explain things better. Perhaps you could accept it as the correct answer to help others facing a similar problem? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what Cake's `isUnique` rule checks for and as a result over complicating things. Cake [defines `isUnique`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Model::Validation::isUnique) as:-

> The data for the field must be unique, it cannot be used by any other rows

When it checks if a value is unique it is smart enough to exclude existing data of the current row (which appears to be what you are attempting to do with your `editunique` rule).

So you just need your validation rules to look like:-

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Kindly provide your email for verification.'
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 255),
            'message' => 'Email cannot be more than 255 characters.'
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Provided Email already exists.'
        )
    )
);
```

This removes the `editunique` rule and drops the `on` condition of your `unique` rule.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

As of cakephp 3.0 in the entities table it should look something like this

```
   namespace App\Model\Table;

   public function validationDefault($validator)
   {
    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->add('email', 'email', [
            'rule' => [$this, 'isUnique'],
            'message' => __('Email already registered')
        ])
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('email', 'Email is Required', function( $context ){
            if(isset($context['data']['role_id']) && $context['data']['role_id'] != 4){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    return $validator;
}
}


function isUnique($email){
    $user = $this->find('all')
        ->where([
                'Users.email' => $email,
          ])
        ->first();
        if($user){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```